Problem with recursive function that sums all numbers in array in Go
I want to sum all the numbers in array using recursive function

import (
    "fmt"
)

func RemoveIndex(s []int, index int) []int {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}

func recursiveSum(arr []int) int {
    if len(arr) == 1 {
        return arr[0]
    }

    sum := arr[0] + recursiveSum(RemoveIndex(arr, 0))
    return sum
}

func main() {
    var arr = []int{2, 4, 6}
    fmt.Println(recursiveSum(arr))
}

I have such code. In fact there isn't any function for deleting element in array by index in Go, so I wrote function that did that. So, generaly I expected to get 12 and for some reason I get 18. Can please someone help and explain what exactly goes wrong here.

The append method will modify an array in place if there is capacity in the underlying array, overwriting the current contents of the slice. Which means arr[0] is always 6 since you get to the end condition first, before the addition is run. If you examined the value of arr, you would see [6, 6, 6].
There's really no need to delete the entry from the slice. Instead just sum the values after the first entry (assuming you really want recursion):
sum := arr[0] + recursiveSum(arr[1:])

Though a much better option is to skip recursion on do this in a standard loop:
sum := 0
for _, i := range arr {
    sum += i
}

